# Customized sorting objects with multiple data fields, python

Tags: python, sorting, object, csv

```
 def sortIt ():
    with open('changed.csv') as infile, open ('sorted.csv','w') as outfile:
    arr = []
    for line in infile:
        if not line:
            info = line.split (',')
            arr.append(information(info[0],info[1],info[2],info[3],info[4]))
    arr.sort(key=lambda y:y.b)
    for x in range (len(arr)):
      outfile.writerow(arr[x].a+","+arr[x].b+","+arr[x].c+","+arr[x].d+","+arr[x].e)
```

so baiscally I am reading data from csv file which is double spaced. Then I would like to store them as an array. Next, I want to sort the array by "b" which is a string.
Print them into another csv file called"sorted"

Q: I am not sure what is wrong with this code, this does not print sorted array into output file.

Expected input: hi,you,are,not,bad
                what,is,up,man,?
Expected output: what,is,up,man,?
                 hi,you,are,not,bad

**EDIT: Information is an object that I created which has variables: a,b,c,d,e. So changed.csv is the file which I will read the data(string type) from. Each line of the data in the file contains 5 different things (a,b,c,d,e) that is separated by ','. Then I read each line individually and get the 5 differnt things (a,b,c,d,e). Then since it is not sorted in any particular order, I will store it in an array so that I can sort it. so the 'b' variable is string. What I meant by sort by 'b' is to sort the string in ascending order(alphabetical order). For instance, 'a' goes before 'c', 'apple' goes before 'banana'. After sorting in this order, I would like to print them all out into a file, 'sorted.csv'. So that I can access it later when I want a specific data using binary search (since it is sort). My problem is that I do not see any thing written in 'sorted.csv' after I run the function.  Sorry for vague description of question, I realize I really need to work on explain my thoughts.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Any example of the input file and expected output?

Comment: @Marcin edit the expected input and output

Comment: @FamilyMaze Sorry, but your question is not very clear. What is `informaton` for example? What are changed.csv and sorted.csv? What do you mean by "sort the array by "b" which is a string"? Please clarify your question. Otherwise, difficult to tell what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for update, i modified your code and made dummy information class to be able to run your code.

```
class information():

    def __init__(self, a,b,c,d,e):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e

    def __str__(self):
        return ",".join([self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d, self.e])

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + ': ' + self.__str__()



def sortIt():
    with open('data.csv', 'r') as infile, open ('sorted.csv','w') as outfile:
        arr = []

        for line in infile:
            if line:
                info = line.rstrip().split(',')
                arr.append(information(*info))

        print(arr)
        arr.sort(key=lambda y:y.b)
        print(arr)

        outfile.write("\n".join(map(str,arr)))


sortIt()
```

The result of print functions:

```
[information: hi,you,are,not,bad, information: what,is,up,man,?]
[information: what,is,up,man,?, information: hi,you,are,not,bad]
```

Hope this helps.